# Solving exponential equations from 2 points

Tags: javascript, equation, algebra, exponential

I have been working on this code for a while now, and since I am only in 9th grade, I don't have much algebra experience. I have tried many things, and this is where my scripts are now.(Note, this is just the JavaScript, the id's being called for are the boxes with the info and the output).

```
 <script>
        function SolveExp() {
          //constants
          var d = document;
          //Point values
          var EX1 = eval(d.getElementById('EX1').value);
          var EX2 = eval(d.getElementById('EX2').value);
          var EY1 = eval(d.getElementById('EY1').value);
          var EY2 = eval(d.getElementById('EY2').value);
          //Exponential Equation y=a*bx
          var a,bx,EQX,EQY;

          //To organize the system for "x"
          if(EX1 > EX2) {
            EQX = EX1 - EX2;
          }
          else if(EX2 > EX1) {
            EQX = EX2 - EX1;
          };
          //To organize the system for "y"
           if(EY1 > EY2) {
            EQY = EY1 / EY2;
           }
          else if(EY2 > EY1) {
             EQY = EY2 / EY1;
           };
           a = -(EY1) + Math.pow(bx,EX1);
          bx = Math.pow(EQY,EQX);
          document.getElementById('ExpEQ').innerHTML = "y = " + a + "(" + bx + ")<sup>x</sup>";
        }
      </script>
```

That only works with "b" in the form y = a(b)<sup>x</sup> from the points (0,4) and (1,8). A is always -3 when I plug those points into the boxes. The equation is completely different when I use points from the same line. Any got solutions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve for?  Give an example of the input and expected output.

Comment: Example: You plug in the points (0,4),(1,8) and you should end up with y=4(2)x (x is superscript). You also plug in (2,16),(3,32) and should get the same equation, but instead it becomes way off. "b" is still the same, but "a" is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use bx in the equation for a before you have assigned it a value. those two lines are out of order. EQX and EQY don't get assigned to anything if EX1 = EX2 or EY1 = EY2. eval is a taboo word in javascript and should be used with extreme caution. Other people will harass you about using it. Read up about why it's bad and decide for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Also, with eval(), if I don't have it in the variable, it doesn't display properly and doesn't say the value within it. Any work-around?

Comment: @Carter it depends on your html for the EX1 element. if it were `<div id="EX1">123</div>` then `document.getElementById('EX1').innerHTML` would give you 123. You could append your HTML to the question.

Comment: OK, I just figured out what was wrong, and I fixed it. I could have hit it with a log(),  but I found an easier way. I will try to find a way to not use the eval() function.